# How do I force the charging to begin immediately and disregard the smart schedule, via the terminal?

Tags: terminal, battery, charging, macos

macOS has a feature that schedules battery charging to optimize battery health. Sometimes one wants to disregard this and start charging immediately as fast as possible. How can I do this programmatically?

Comment: Does it need to be programmatically? What's the complete workflow? There is a "Charge to Full" item in the battery menulet, or in the Control Centre's battery section. You could probably turn off "Optimize Battery Charging" with a `defaults write` command, which would do it.